# Мультиязычное приложение на C

Tags: c, локализация, интернационализация

Подскажите, как в *C* обычно делают мультиязичность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

например, с помощью [*gnu/gettext*](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) (там присутствует ссылка на подробнейшую англо-язычную документацию).

есть [статья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) в русскоязычной википедии, в которой приведён небольшой пример.

там же, к примеру, упоминается и краткое русско-язычное [руководство](http://localization-software.blogspot.ru/2009/09/software-localization-using-gettext.html).

Comment: А как gettext подключить? Нужно проинклудить заголовочный файл наверно какой-то, в гугле везде примеры без инклуда

Comment: @Виталий, если вам непонятно это из приведённых ссылок и подробнейшей документации, задайте, пожалуйста, **новый** вопрос.

Comment: @Виталий, и я бы рекомендовал начинать не с поиска «инклудов», а с прочтения хотя бы приведённых русско-язычных источников. интернационализация программы — это комплексный процесс, не решаемый «добавлением инклуда».

Comment: Спасибо, нашел инклуд, а остальное думаю легко пойму, в php gettext юзаю

Comment: А получше что-нибудь есть для C++? в qt более удобный иснструмент но он только для qt

Comment: @Виталий, *в php gettext* — это он и есть. биндинги к библиотеке gettext написаны, пожалуй, ко всем популярным языкам программирования под всеми популярными операционными системами.

Comment: @zenden2k, *А получше что-нибудь есть?* — наверняка есть. основное преимущество *gnu/gettext* — его переносимость. биндинги к библиотеке написаны, пожалуй, ко всем популярным языкам программирования под всеми популярными операционными системами.

Answer (score 0):

в linux обычно используют gettext с C/C++.  Если Qt, там свой инструментарий.