# Локализация приложения

Tags: delphi, интернационализация

Какие готовые средства локализации или механизмы можно использовать в приложении?

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, на [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438715/178576). в частности, «биндинги» есть и для *c++*, и для *c#*, и для *pascal*, и «персонально» для [*delphi, c++ builder, kylix, freepascal and lazarus*](http://dxgettext.po.dk/)

Comment: Попробуйте gnugettext