# Языковые параметры для функции t()

Tags: drupal, интернационализация

Описываю мультиязычный интерфейс на сайте и не получается найти формирование  языковых констант.
В собственных модулях, для некоторых частей интерфейса использую функцию **t("Text msg")**. 
Где описываются данные параметры в друпале, что бы можно было перевести на несколько языков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по названию функции, похоже, что вы используете [*gnu/gettext*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438715/178576).

перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231814/4827341) (исходный текст — в виде комментариев).

необходимые шаги:

1. для генерации `.pot`-файла установите модуль [Translation template extractor](http://drupal.org/project/potx)

2. перейдите на закладку "Extract strings" в *Locale administration interface*, выберите ваш модуль и заполните форму. вы получите сгенерированный *template*-файл.

3. после этого вы можете перевести строки с помощью инструмента вроде  [*poedit*](http://www.poedit.net) (в дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux* присутствует в виде одноимённого пакета).

4. после завершения перевода файлы должны быть скопированы в под-каталог "translations" каталога вашего модуля, и *drupal* автоматически импортирует их при установке вашего модуля.